# Xamarin Android Application Use In Visual Studio 2015

Tags: xamarin

I am in new xamarin android application developer.So I Need to Some templates Of Login Page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you searched the internet for any solution?

You might want to take a look at this xamarin component:https://components.xamarin.com/view/loginscreen/

Hope it helps, but please do some research before posting or at least explain a little more your problem and what you have done.